# How do you add a gradient to strokes as a whole object (not individually)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I am trying to add a gradient (in the lines not as filling in the shapes) from one side to the other in the artwork attached.
When trying to add this gradient, Illustrator adds a gradient to each stroke individually. I want a gradient done to the entire piece as one whole.
I did try to Object > Path > Join, to make the work as one. However this adds more random lines to the artwork, destroying the work.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a compound path. Simply select all your lines and go to "*Object → Compound Path → Make*" or hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.

Your individual lines with a gradient stroke applied:

[image]

The same lines converted to a compound path:

[image]

Another option is to use the Appearance panel (*Window → Appearance*) and apply the gradient stroke to a a group or layer containing the lines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trying goint to *Object>Expand*, then in the popup window click both *"Fill"* & *"Stroke"* and click ok. Then go to *Pathfinder* and click *Unite*. If you don't see your Pathfinder window got to *Window>Pathfinder*. Hope that does the trick.